# Power Supply -from single source

Tags: power

I have two components , i need to power from external source using single source, how can i do.

a)  first device requires 5V,5A
b)  second device requires 12V,1A

Both should be powered from external source using a single source

Comment: You can use a PC PSU. It's a "single" source and it can provide both voltages.

Comment: You haven't stated the spec of your single source of power.

Comment: Single power supply is like mine 230V supply

Answer (score 1):

You either

1. Use two power supplies, one 5 V and one 12 V.
2. Use a 12 V power supply and a switching regulator to step down to provide the 5 V supply.

Power required on the 5 V circuit is *P = V I = 5 × 5 = 25* W (and allow another 20% or so for regulator losses). The 12 V circuit requires 12 W so if you use the switching regulator option the 12 V PSU must be capable of giving out 25 × 120% + 12 = 42 W.

Comment: "Both should be powered from external source using a single source" that doesn't fit well with your first point or does it? Using a combined 5 V / 12 V PSU might be an option instead.

Comment: The single source could be the mains supply to the device. The question is vague.

Comment: If two power source to be used than two power cables will comeout , I dont require that ....is there any option using two power supply & bring one cable out & giving power to two power supply

Comment: Can you suggest me a 12V V PSU

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a dual power supply, using a single transformer with two secondary windings for a 5V 5A regulator and a 12V 1A one, would fit the bill.